# Running Python 3 streaming job in EMR without bootstraping

Tags: python-3.x, hadoop-streaming, emr

I haven't got a chance to try but I am wondering if EMR instances has Python 3 installed out of the box. From my experiment I do know it has Python 2 for sure. If there is an easy way of checking default packages (installed) given an AMI, that would be great to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ["AMI versions supported"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/ami-versions-supported.html), Python 3 is not supported yet.